# How to get border animation to delay on scroll?

Tags: css, animation, border, delay

I've done some custom animations on a couple of borders. I'm using Divi, so I added a divider with the class: border. I have one on top of the page which loads fine, but I want to delay the animations on the lines lower down on the page. Right now when you scroll to the bottom, the animation has already happened. animation-delay is not working in CSS. Any ideas? Link to page: https://higleycabinets.wpengine.com/